# Download Inventory File from AWS S3

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have configured AWS to automatically create an inventory file, in the following location. Just to explain an inventory file is a `csv.gz` file with a directory listing of an entire bucket (named Bucket1). On a weekly basis a file with a gibberish name is created here:

```
Location: Bucket2\Inventory\Data\filename_gibberish.csv.gz
```

**Question:** I wish for my bash script to locate the latest inventory file based on the "last modified" time-stamp on AWS. Then check if my local directory has this file? If not, download it.

Pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will *list* the most recently created object:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --prefix Inventory/Data/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

It can be combined with a copy command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --prefix Inventory/Data/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text) inventory.csv.gz
```

(Note that the bucket name appears twice in that command.)

Comment: Thanks John. The list command works very well. but the second command throws an error saying key does not exists. Seems like it tries to find a truncated version of the bucket's keyname

Comment: Also, this does not check if the file already exists in my local pc. if yes, it should not download again

Comment: You can use `aws s3 sync` for Johns commands rather than `aws s3 sync`, this will do the same thing but will only copy new and updated files instead. "Recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination." :)

Comment: My code above copies the most recent object (with an unknown name) to the local directory with a specific name. If you wish to retain the 'random' name that AWS Inventory provides, then I agree you should instead just use `aws s3 sync` to download any new files to your local directory. It is then your problem to figure out when each one was generated.

Comment: Thanks both. One more question plz:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212608/aws-cli-to-run-sql-query

Comment: Hi John. 1 more ques pls. The following 2 commands work perfectly as expected. `var=$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket project1 --prefix project2/Inventory/data/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text)  &&  echo $var`.  The following does not work, can you pls advice why?  `aws s3 cp s3://project1/$var inventory.csv.gz`

Comment: @rogerwhite A good way to debug that is to put `echo` at the front of the line. It will print out the command that is executing and you can see whether it got the correct command: `echo aws s3 cp s3://project1/$var inventory.csv.gz`

Comment: Good point, the echo command did not return the correct string. Seems like the string was over-written somehow. How would I do this? The first command helps me check if the inventory is already downloaded. If not, I wish to download it. This will save avoid downloading the file, unless needed

Comment: Just make sure your first command (`var=$(...)`) is working correctly first.

Comment: I think i figured it out. I need to `| tr -d '\r'`

Comment: AH! Or, try putting `[Key]` in square brackets... `[-1].[Key]`. It _might_ help.