# AWS CLI to run SQL query

Tags: python, bash, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have the following code written in Python. I wish to migrate it over to Bash, or use just plain old AWS CLI. Mission is to run a SQL query on a S3 bucket, using S3 Select. Note: the files in S3 are all gziped.

**Existing Python Code (working)**

```
ACCESS_KEY = 'Key1'
SECRET_KEY = 'Key2'
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

r = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket='bkt1',
    Key=file2search,
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression="SELECT * FROM s3object s where Lower(s._1) = (%r)" % ("SEARCH_STRING"),
    InputSerialization = {'CompressionType': 'GZIP', 'CSV': {
        'AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter': True,
        'QuoteEscapeCharacter': '"',
        'RecordDelimiter': '\n',
        'FieldDelimiter': ':',
        }},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {
            'QuoteEscapeCharacter': '"',
            'RecordDelimiter': '\n',
            'FieldDelimiter': ':',
        }}
)
```

**Bash Code (NOT working)**

```
SEARCH_STRING="hello@world.com"
aws s3api select-object-content \
    --bucket projectbucket2 \
    --key abc.gz \
    --expression "SELECT * FROM s3object s where Lower(s._1) = \'$SEARCH_STRING\'" \
    --expression-type 'SQL' \
    --input-serialization '{"CSV": {}, "CompressionType": "GZIP"}' \
    --output-serialization '{"CSV": {}}' "output.csv"
```

The code throws an error: `An error occurred (LexerInvalidChar) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: Invalid character at line 1, column 46.`
Do pls help.

Comment: Yes, you can run an S3 Select command using the AWS CLI: [select-object-content — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/select-object-content.html). Please show us what you have tried and what problems you are facing.

Comment: Thanks John. pls refer to my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked perfectly fine for me on Ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-201:~$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.38 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-1023-aws exe/x86_64.ubuntu.18

ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-201:~$ echo $SEARCH_STRING
taipei 101

ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-201:~$ aws s3api select-object-content --bucket my-bucket --key towers.csv --expression "SELECT * FROM s3object s where Lower(s._2) = '$SEARCH_STRING'" --expression-type 'SQL' --input-serialization '{"CSV": {}, "CompressionType": "NONE"}'     --output-serialization '{"CSV": {}}' "output.csv"

ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-201:~$ cat output.csv 
5,Taipei 101,Taipei,Taiwan,509,1670,101,2004
```

I was using AWS CLI v2.

Comment: Thanks John. I think I figured the issue out. If you look at my python query, you would notice that I have the RecordDelim as "\n" and FieldDelim as ":" ..   Thanks I managed to fix the code... One more question pls, what if I do not wish for the output to go in a file. Could I display the output on the screen? Thanks for all your help, you have been great, with all the back n forth

Comment: It appears that the `outfile` is required for that command.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-using the single-quote (`'`) character.

For example: `--input-serialization '{'CompressionType':` The first quote opens your JSON, but then the quote immediately after the curly bracket closes the quote.

Instead, try experimenting with alternating use of the single and double-quote. For example:

```
--input-serialization '--input-serialization '{"CompressionType": "GZIP", "CSV": {
```

This allows the single-quote to contain the entire JSON, while the double-quote is used *inside* the JSON.

The result would look *something* like this (I didn't test it):

```sh
aws s3api select-object-content \
    --bucket bkt1 \
    --key filename.gz \
    --expression "SELECT * FROM s3object s where Lower(s._1) = '$SEARCH_STRING'" \
    --expression-type 'SQL' \
    --input-serialization '{"CompressionType": "GZIP", "CSV": {
            "AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter": True,
            "QuoteEscapeCharacter": "\"",
            "RecordDelimiter": "\n",
            "FieldDelimiter": ":",
            }}' \
    --output-serialization '{"CSV": {
                "QuoteEscapeCharacter": "\"",
                "RecordDelimiter": "\n",
                "FieldDelimiter": ":",
            }}'
```

Comment: Thanks John. but doesnt work. To confirm if I am initializing the variable correctly   `SEARCH_STRING = "something to search"`. If this is correct, I get an error saying `Unexpected operator OPERATOR:'%' `

Comment: Oh! Where is `SEARCH_STRING` coming from? If it is defined as a shell variable, then use `$SEARCH_STRING`, but it would need to be quoted. This might then be impacted by the single-quote stopping substitution, so it might need to be escaped: `--expression "SELECT * FROM s3object s where Lower(s._1) = \'$SEARCH_STRING\'" \ `

Comment: still doesnt work sir  :(    `An error occurred (LexerInvalidChar) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: Invalid character at line 1, column 46.`

Comment: I have updated the code on my questions, to help explain

Comment: I got it working by changing `\'$SEARCH_STRING\'` into `'$SEARCH_STRING'`.

Comment: yup, already tried that. in that case the script doesnt throw an error, but doesnt work as expected. I think it is trying to search either with the quotes included in, or else '$' included in

Comment: The bash version in your question worked fine for me. The output appeared in `output.csv`. I used my own CSV file, uncompressed (so set compression to `NONE`. I'm on a Mac, Windows might differ.

Comment: I tried on ubuntu as well as cygin on windows 10. Exact same error given in the question. In case I remove the back-slash to escape the quotes, then I get a blank output - meaning the search string is not parsed correctly

Comment: Does it work if you temporary put the actual search term into the quotes (without using a variable)?

Comment: Hi John. I tried that as well. If I add the email in single-quotes, it would return an empty output.csv file (no error msg). However, the command works perfectly, if I replace the expression with `--expression "select * from s3object limit 10"`

Comment: Pls help ...   :'(